# Download and install an app without App Store iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I want my app to be downloaded from the sever without going to the App Store.I have an  ad-hoc distribution build,then how can I deploy this to the server and download the app by scanning the link using QR code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't really work for wide-spread distribution of your app unless you're looking to distribute internally as part of the Enterprise Developer program. If you're looking to distribute to beta testers you could take a look at this:

http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/

Also, several services are offered such as TestFlight or HockeyApp that make doing this a little easier.